# How to automatically insert factoryid and categoryid into a table when submitting form - codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter, join

I am using 3 tables for joining.
I have a form where i can add a factory. I also can choose a category for that specific factory. 
i use the following tables:

```
factorycategories
-----------------
idfactorycategories
idfactories
idcategories
(in this table i use a join to show the categories and factories on one page)

factories
---------
idfactories
factoryname
address
country
telephone
...
...

categories
----------
idcategories
category
```

I want to insert the last inserted idcategories and idfactories in my factorycategories table.
How can i do this?

**My model for inserting the form values:**

```
function addbedrijf()
{
    $data1 = array(
       'Bedrijfsnaam' => $this->input->post('Bedrijfsnaam'),
       'Postcode' => $this->input->post('Postcode'),
       'Plaats' => $this->input->post('Plaats'),
       'Telefoonnummer' => $this->input->post('Telefoonnummer'),
       'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'),
       'Website' => $this->input->post('Website'),
       'Profiel' => $this->input->post('Profiel'),
       'Adres' => $this->input->post('Adres'),
       'logo' => $this->input->post('logo')
    );
    $this->db->insert('bedrijven', $data1);
}
```

**My model function for showing categories and factories on the same page:**

```
function get_result($idbedrijven)
{
    $this->db->where('bedrijven.idbedrijven', $idbedrijven);
    $this->db->join('bedrijven', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idbedrijven = bedrijven.idbedrijven');
    $this->db->join('categorieen', 'bedrijfcategorieen.idcategorieen = categorieen.idcategorieen');
    $this->db->group_by('Categorie', 'idbedrijven', 'idcategorieen');
    $result = $this->db->get('bedrijfcategorieen', 1);
    return $result->result(); 
}
```

Hope i provided enough code for you guys.

Edit:

the code that i have so far using the example below:

```
function addbedrijf()
{
    $data1 = array(
       'Bedrijfsnaam' => $this->input->post('Bedrijfsnaam'),
       'Postcode' => $this->input->post('Postcode'),
       'Plaats' => $this->input->post('Plaats'),
       'Telefoonnummer' => $this->input->post('Telefoonnummer'),
       'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'),
       'Website' => $this->input->post('Website'),
       'Profiel' => $this->input->post('Profiel'),
       'Adres' => $this->input->post('Adres'),
       'logo' => $this->input->post('logo')
    );
    $this->db->insert('bedrijven',$data1);

    if($this->db->affected_rows() >= 1)
    {
    $this->insert_bedrijfcat($this->db->insert_id);
    }else{
    return FALSE
    }
}

function insert_bedrijfcat($id)
{
    $this->db->insert('bedrijfcategorieen',array('idbedrijven'=>$id));

    return $this->db->affected_rows() ?= 1 ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting data to the `bedrijven` table

and you want to get the last inserted id of

`categories` and `factories` table then insert it to `factorycategories` table also?

THe question is when inserting data to `bedrijven` table do you insert data to the

`categories` and `factories` table ? Because if you do you can use `$this->db->insert_id` to get the last input id of your `categories` and `factories` table, if not you need to query a different sql to get both last input id.

**EDIT**

here so i modified a some code example

```
class Some_model Extends CI_Model
{
   public function insert_factory($data)
   {
      $this->db->insert('factory_table',$data);

      //if has affected rows
      if($this->db->affected_rows() >= 1)
      {
        // the insert was successfull send the last insert id to another method
        $this->insert_to_factorycateg($this->db->insert_id);
      }else{
         return FALSE
     }
   }

   //method to insert to factorycateg
   public function insert_to_factorycateg($id)
   {
       //insert 
      $this->db->insert('factorycategories',array('factoryid'=>$id));

      //if affected rows return true else false
      return $this->db->affected_rows() >= 1 ? TRUE : FALSE;
   }
}
```

Comment: yes i have a form where i add factories to the database. i still need to make the function for choosing a category. but i just want to, when i add a factory. that the id of that factory is automatically added to the factorycategories table.

Comment: you can use `this->db->insert_id` as stated a while ago, you can also use it when inserting to the category just by creating another variable to hold it or array.

Comment: could you give an example? i'm still a bit new to codeigntier and i searched on google fort insert_id but could not figure out.

Comment: do i have to specify this in my controller too? because i am getting a server error.

Comment: i just get an server error. so that's likely an fatal php error. i can't see what the error is.

Comment: added my code i have so far (note: i've changed some names to match my tables)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28959/discussion-between-tomexsans-and-kees-sonnema)